Limit value depending on a function's asymptotics
I want to compute the limit of the following function when $n\to\infty$:
$$f(n)=\frac{2 n \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{g(n)}}{2-3 n \ln \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{g(n)}\right)}$$
It depends on a function $g(n)$ which can have several asymptotic bounds, depending on which the limit will result in a different value:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0 \quad[O(g(n))\subset O(n)]$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=\frac{2}{3e - 3e \ln(e-1)} \quad[g(n)=\Theta(n)]$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}+e^\gamma} \quad[g(n)=\Theta(nH_n)]$$
As seen, when $g(n)$ is asymptotically smaller than $n$, it tends to 0. In case it grows exactly as $n$ does, it converges in a real value, as well as in the $g(n)=\Theta(nH_n)$ case.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=\frac{2}{3}\enspace[g(n)=\Theta(n\ln(\ln(n)))];\enspace \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=\frac{2}{3}\quad[g(n)=\Theta(n\ln(\sqrt{n}))]$$
As $g(n)$ can't exceed the $\Theta(nH_n)$ bound, I'm interested in knowing if between $O(n)$ and $O(nH_n)$ the limit converges to the same value for all functions within such range. I tried with the above 2 and it seems the limit converges to $\frac{2}{3}$, but I didn't find a way to prove it for all functions of the set $O(nH_n)-O(n)$.
Also, is there any way to prove the $O(g(n))\subset O(n)$ case for all functions of the set $O(n)$?

For each natural $n$ put $h(n)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{g(n)}$.
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2h(n)}{\frac{2}{n}-3\ln\left(1-h(n)\right)},$$
so we need to have $h(n)<1$ for each natural $n$.
According to my answer to your other bounty question (from MathOverflow), the bounded limit $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} h(n)$ exists iff there exists the limit $M=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g(n)}n\in (-\infty,\infty]$. In the latter case $L=e^{-M}$ (we consider $e^{-\infty}$ to be $0$). Since $h(n)<1$ for each natural $n$, $L\le 1$. Then
$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ is $-\frac{2L}{3\ln(1-L)}$, if $0<L<1$, and is $0$, if $L=1$.
If $L=0$ then the situation is more subtle. We have
$$\lim_{h\to 0} -\frac{\ln (1-h)}{h}=(\ln (1+h))'{\Large|}_{h=1}=\frac 1{1+h}{\Huge|}_{h=1}=1.$$
It suggests that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{\frac {2}{nh(h)}+3}.$$
Suppose now that there is no limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(n)$. Then the sequence $(h(n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a cluster point $L\in (0,1]$. For each $h\in (0,1)$ we have $\ln (1-h)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {h^k}k$. Then the function $\frac{\ln (1-h)}{h}$ decreases. Suppose that there exists $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$. This is only possible when the sequence $(h(n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has exactly two cluster points $L$ and $0$ . Moreover, the previous paragraph suggests that for any infinite subset $S$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty,\, n\in S} h(n)=0$ we should have also
$$\lim_{n\to\infty,\, n\in S} \frac{2}{\frac {2}{nh(h)}+3}=
\begin{cases} -\frac{2L}{3\ln(1-L)}, & \text{if } L<1\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,0, & \text{if } L=1.
\end{cases}$$

I'm going to write what I've observed.
Your $f(n)$ can be written as
$$f(n)=\frac{2}{\frac{2}{nF}+3\times\frac{\ln \left(1-F\right)}{-F}}$$
where $F:=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{g(n)}$.
If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}{n}=\infty$, then we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}F=0$ since
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln F&=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(-g(n)\ln\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)\bigg)
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{g(n)}{n}\times\underbrace{\frac{-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}}{1-\frac 1n}}_{\to\ -1}\bigg)
\\\\&=-\infty\end{align}$$
Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}F=0$, we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln \left(1-F\right)}{-F}=1$$
Now, we have
$$\begin{align}\ln(nF)&=\ln n+\ln F
\\\\&=\ln n-\frac{g(n)}{n-1}\ln\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\bigg)^{n-1}
\\\\&=\ln(n)\bigg(1-\frac{g(n)}{n\ln n}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n-1})^{n-1}}{1-\frac 1n}}_{\to 1}\bigg)\end{align}$$
So, if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}{n\ln n}\lt 1$, then since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(nF)=\infty$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}nF=\infty$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\frac{2}{nF}+3\times\frac{\ln \left(1-F\right)}{-F}}=\frac 23$$
